# REACT: How to update the list after click button EDIT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make request to the server using `fetch` and get response - category list. This list I display in view- table. Near each category on the right I have button **Edit**. When I click this button appears **form** with one **input** and button **submit** and I can change title some category. I use API method `PUT` that change category.

But when I click button `submit` after editing title of the category my list the same. Because list is not update. And at that moment I still don't see the title name changed.

### My list update only I reload page in browser

#### How to update the list after click button EDIT?

`/.....` - Code which I delete in question just to have less code in the question

### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    numberId: "",              
    isOpened: false,
    /.....
  });
 
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(/......) {
        const response = await fetch(`/.....`, {
          method: 'GET',  headers: {/.....}   });
        const data = await response.json();
             setValue(prev => ({
                ...prev,
                listCategory: data.data,
                /......
             }));
    }  fetchData(/.....); 
  }, [/.....]);

const changeId = (argNumberId) => {         
     setValue({
        ...value,
        numberId: argNumberId,
        isOpened: true
    });};
    
  return (
    <div>
               <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory}  changeId={changeId}  valueId={value.numberId} />
    
                //COMPONENT WHICH CHANGE TITLE CATEGORY:
               {value.isOpened && <ChangeCategory value={value.numberId} />}    
   </div>);};
```

### ChangeCategory.js:

```
const ChangeCategory = (props) => {
    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
          title: '',
      },
    onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/${props.value}`, { // props.value - id category which I edit, I get this id from field numberId in state
            method:'PUT',  body: JSON.stringify(formValues),  headers: {/.....} });
        const data = await response.json();  
       }});
    
   return (    
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       <InputCategory
         label="title"
         id="title" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'title',
           value: values.title,
           onChange: handleChange,   
       }}/>
          <button type="submit">Edit</button>
     </form>
   </div>);};
```

### Table.js:

```
export default (props) => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>  
        <th>TITLE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id} </td>
          <td>{item.title} </td>
          // BUTTON WHICH OPEN MODAL AND CHANGE ID IN STATE
          <td><button onClick={() => props.changeId(item.id)}>Edit</button></td> 
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Comment: Should you call `fetchData()` again after successfully submit data

Comment: @massam Can you show how to do this in code? And in what file to do it.... Because I am begginer.

Comment: I think you should update your values, according to response of your put request.

Comment: I agree with @acbay. No need to fetch data again. After title is successfully submitted, map `listCategory` category and set new title to the changed one.

Comment: @radovix Can you answered my question and write that you propsed in code?

Comment: @A. Ecrubit gave you pretty good explanation in his answer.

Comment: @radovix When I wrote like answer A. Ecrubit I have error:
https://i.piccy.info/i9/6521c44da546e8cd6bed48de1c736b0c/1588333551/21651/1372209/Screenshot_4.png 
Can you know why it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the state directly in your `onSubmit` method, after a successful  API call. 
You already have the data so just add the method to handle the update :

```js
onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
              const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${listRoute}/${props.value}`, { // props.value - id category which I edit, I get this id from field numberId in state
                  method:'PUT',  body: JSON.stringify(formValues),  headers: {/.....} });
              const data = await response.json();  
                // ADD THIS :
               props.updateList(data.data);
       }});
```

You need to add `updateList` in you parent component : `Home.js`

```js
const updateList = data => {

    setValue({ ...value, listCategory: data })
}
```

and pass it as a props to `ChangeCategory`

```js
{value.isOpened && <ChangeCategory 
                       value={value.numberId} 
                       updateList={updateList}
                   />}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and then I have error when click button submit in my edit form:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/6521c44da546e8cd6bed48de1c736b0c/1588333551/21651/1372209/Screenshot_4.png

Comment: See my new comment because I first the wrong screenshot did

Comment: I updated the param passed to `updateList` in my answer, you have to check what your fetch method return, if it's like the GET one, then data.data also returns the list, it should work.

Comment: then error :
http://i.piccy.info/i9/d4e7f612c2aa751476e24391031d2ac5/1588342551/23459/1372209/Screenshot_3.png

Comment: We can't do the work for you, you should try to debug it, add some console.log or a breakpoint after your api call to see what you receive, check the value of `listCategory` before and after setValue in`updateList ` You may have to adapt it.

Comment: I think it related with method `updateList` because in past I have a similar problem, but unfortunately i don't remember what i corrected in the similar method. It maybe related with this `...value`. I just begginer that it is difficult for me to debug it...

Comment: `...valueù is just js destructuring to keep the other value in the `value` object. My function actually does exactly what you are doing with `setValue` in `useEffect` so I don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe What screenshot do I send you so you can help me fix this problem?